# Xcode - Cannot modify plist using PlistBuddy in script

Tags: ios, xcode, plistbuddy

I want to set UIFileSharingEnabled key to true using script.
Script code:

```
echo "set file sharing to true"

BASE_PLIST="${SRCROOT}/Customization/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :UIFileSharingEnabled" "$BASE_PLIST"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled bool true" "$BASE_PLIST"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :UIFileSharingEnabled" "$BASE_PLIST"
```

console print:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: remove "bool"

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled true" "$BASE_PLIST"
```